# Installation error while installing scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-8.1

My system is windows 8.1 and installed python 3.7.2. Now, whenever I try to install -> `pip install scrapy`.

It always shows me an error mention below:

```
error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5lpvl9q3\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5pmlq_y_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5lpvl9q3\Twisted\
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Python 3.7.2? Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have microsoft sdk's installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist, you can try to upgrade setuptools and try again. (You did not specify is there problem only with Scrapy or with everything else you're trying to install?)

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

My suggestion is to use virtual env or **conda** on windows.

Here's how:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows

Comment: May I install Miniconda or Anaconda for windows?

Comment: Which one is best?

Comment: You can do both. If you are new to Python, go with Anaconda because it has some built in packages and you can easily create environments, upgrade packages etc.

Comment: Yes, you can install on Windows - https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows

Comment: `Anaconda` work. Thanks